# How do I restore or add a previously removed built-in or stock iOS app in iOS10?

Tags: ios

I have deleted or removed a stock iOS app. How do I restore that app if I want it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add a previously removed built-in app
>
> 1. Go to the App Store and search for the app.
> 2. Tap Download to restore
>      the app. Wait for the app to restore, then open it from your Home
>      screen.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204221